# Titling texts in Latin

Tags: grammar-choice, word-order

So, I'm puzzling through a grammar structure in Latin, mostly after just cramming a bunch of grammar into my head. I'm trying to concoct the title of an imaginary text.

I'd like to check whether I've got correct grammar and a natural word order in an example phrase.

So... does this sound vaguely right?

GLADIUS AUREUS MILITIS MORTUI

Golden Sword of [the] Dead Soldier

Note: I realize there's lots of words for soldiers, and this may not be the best choice.

However, what I'm *really* concerned about is the **grammar** and **word order**. The assumption is the phrase structure would be the title of an imaginary book, and my main questions are:

- Is the word order correct? Does the parallelism between the pairs (NOUN + ADJ | NOUN + ADJ) feel natural?

I saw something about "hyperbaton" as a stylistic device but didn't see any use of it that matched this kind of structure, nor anything that suggested it was necessary. Might hyperbaton (or some other stylistic variation) be used for a title like this, and if so, how?

- Is there a preference for nouns and adjectives to match not just declension, but also declension type (i.e. the sound of their declined suffix)? In other words, might one choose a noun that has a matching adjective that ends with the same sound, or purposefully avoid it, or was this a case of personal taste (or of the larger phrase)?

In other words, to take a variant, which sounds better: MILITARIS EXANIMIS or MILITARIS MORTUI?

- Is the grammar actually correct? (The first noun being nominative, the second as genitive because the first noun is "of" (i.e. property or possession of) the second. I've declined the adjectives to match the nouns they modify.)

Any advice you can give me would be much appreciated. Thanks!